# CSS Grid issues in internet explorer

Tags: css

I have a grid gallery on my website

```
.work_gallery_module
{
  display:grid;
  display:-ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns:auto auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap:15px;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto auto;

  padding:0px 20px;
}
```

But the grid is not displaying in the internet explorer instead of all images it is displaying only single image.

Comment: what's the version of your internet explorer?

Comment: which internet explorer version you are using? Because 16.0 and above version only supports `display:grid`, previous versions will be not support

Comment: I am using version 11.8

Comment: @Udayavani in 11.8 it will not support

Comment: is there any version specific stylings

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=grid Please see it here

Comment: For more information [check this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`display:grid;` property are not supported by Older version of Internet Explorer which is previous version of 16.0. Based on your comment you are using 11.8 version, so it will be not works. So you can use `grid` property latest version of Internet Explorer, if you want to use `grid` property in older version of IE which is above 8.0 try the below code.

`display:table` and `display:table-cell or table-column`

Comment: Get the [Latest version of edge here](https://microsoft-edge.en.softonic.com/download)